# Cannot boot PC after installing new CPU

Tags: cpu, hardware-failure

I installed a X5470 in an old Dell Vostro 410 tower that originally had Q6600 in it.

It booted just fine and operated just fine. The HWiNFO and CPU-Z reported the CPU correctly. Windows, however was showing old Q6600 CPU in both System Information as well as Task Manager.

I went into Device Manager and uninstalled all 4 instances of Q6600 cores, thinking Windows would automatically detect the new CPU and would load correct drivers for it. Unfortunately after reboot, it is stuck in endless loop. I can go into BIOS that shows correct CPU, however past the BIOS screen I momentarily see Windows 10 logo and sometimes "preparing automatic repair" message (presumably as a result of previous unsuccessful boot). Shortly after, the PC reboots.

I have no idea how to solve this. One thought I had is to put back the old Q6600, try to let the PC recognize that CPU, then swap it again with X5470 and try to somehow load correct drivers some other way. I would like to avoid that if possible as I'd have to remove heat sink and reapply thermal paste twice.

Any other solutions I could try before I resort to this?

the CPU was purchased with a LGA771-775 mod sticker. Like I said above, it worked flawlessly, until I removed the drivers from the device manager and rebooted with the hopes it would load the new CPU drivers. In addition, this CPU came from a working LGA775 board with the above mod.

Thanks.

Comment: Just an update. I went ahead and put back old Q6600 CPU. It booted up. Then shut down, replaced it again with new X5470 - booted up. System Information was still showing Q6600. I rebooted immediately and that's when the reboot loop starts - on a second reboot.

Comment: Where exactly during boot does it loop?

Comment: @moab Right after bios is loaded and Windows starting to load. I found another person having same exact issue with this processor. Interestingly, x5450 cpu is not affected by the same issue. Must be a driver incompatibility with Win 10. Makes me wonder what would happen if I were to boot to a Win7 or earlier from a USB drive. I may try that to eliminate hardware compatibility. Also makes me wonder if upgrading to Win 10 after the chip is working, would load necessary drivers to make Win10 compatible.